# Is there a library that persists jung graphs from a datastore/database

Tags: java, graph, persistence, jung

I am looking for a way to persist [jung graphs](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) in a database or datastore. Is there a functionality in jung that I could use for this purpose? Maybe there is a library I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What JUNG provides as of now is just the ability to save to GraphML, or to persist graphs to object files.

You could use JUNGs GraphML capabilities to write the graph out to an XML file and then have that read in to a database of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I persist [SparseMultigraph](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/SparseMultigraph.html) structure in [OrientDB](http://orientdb.com/orientdb/)